# Adding an ellipsis using 'Angular-once' (which doesn't allow {{bind 1}{{bind 2}})

Tags: angularjs, binding, angular-once

I'm replacing some bindings in giant list with **[Angular once](https://github.com/tadeuszwojcik/angular-once)**. However, I cant figure out how to replace the following {{}} binding with once:

I'm replacing the following working code:

```
<div class="question">
    {{result.Question | limitTo: 175}}{{result.Question.length > 175 ? '...' : ''}}
</div>
```

Here's what I have so far, everything else I try fails:

```
<div class="question">
    <p once-text="result.Question | limitTo: 175"></p>
</div>
```

### Question:

Using Angular once, how can I accomplish the same side-by-side binding statement that was possible in native Angular?

Comment: Why not create custom `filter` to check length and append `...` after text. Then you can use both filters in same expression: `once-text="result.Question | limitTo: 175 | customFilterName"`

Comment: I'm new to angular, I'll look into how to make a custom filter. Thanks

Comment: Link for custom filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following ways you can write filter to add `...`, it will serve the purpose of `limitTo` also

```
moduleName.filter('addEllipsis', function() {
  return function(input, length) {
    length = length || 100; //default value for length
    return input.length > length ? input.substring(0, length) + "..." : input;
  };
});
```

Now you can use it as follows:

```
once-text="result.Question | addEllipsis" //with default length of 100
```

OR

```
once-text="result.Question | addEllipsis: 175" //with explicit length
```

Comment: I updated my question title to better suit your answer / my needs